# FatFs. How to find the end address and start address of a file on a USB drive?

Tags: stm32, usb

`USB` drive connected to [STM32F407VGT6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f405rg.pdf)

I need to find the end address and start address of `text` and `non-text` files.
The file is located on a `USB` drive.

Are there special functions for finding the end and beginning of a file?
Like the `fseek` function. (`SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_END`)
The fseek function does not suit me, because I need to work with a USB drive.

I could find the address of the end of a text file like this:

```
char line[1];
while(f_gets(line, 2, &USBHFile))
{
}
pos= f_tell(&USBHFile);
printf("%d\n", pos);
```

And I think the address of the beginning of the file is always zero.

`Non-text` files do not have `EOF` and the end of the file cannot be found this way.

Comment: I think you have an X-Y problem here. Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish. Files on nornal filesystems (FAT32, NTFS, ext4, whatever) don't have "start" ot "end" addresses, regardless of the medium. There's no guarantee a file is contiguous: they consist of indexed sequences of blocks. If you just want the file _size_, fseek/ftell do work fine on files on a USB drive.

Comment: I need to know the end address of the BMP file.
Because I need to read the BMP file from the end.
> fseek/ftell do work fine on files on a USB drive<
I need to work with USBHFile.
f_tell(&USBHFile);

Comment: Is your program making use``FatFs`` (a generic FAT file system module for small embedded systems)? If so can you edit the question to the manual for the ``FatFs`` software in use, as not sure what the limitations of that are.

Comment: Yes, I use FatFs.
I still don’t really understand what the differences are between a simple Fat.
I added FatFs in the title of the topic, I hope this is enough.

Comment: Files in a filesystem like FatFS are not typically stored in contiguous clusters, so there's no guarantee that the actualy memory address of the end of te file will be greater then the memory address of the start of the file. You write "I could find the address of the end of a text file like this:" and then show some code - but that code doesn't give you an address, it gives you the size of the file. If that's all you need, then just use the `f_size` function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need a "start" and "end address" to read a file with FatFs. Just use `f_read()`. It's not clear what you mean about reading "from the end." Are you trying to invert, rotate or mirror an image this way? If so you have asked **entirely** the wrong question and are tumbling down a rabbit hole that will not help you.

Comment: @TypeIA For context, .BMP files store the lines of image data in bottom to top order, so some peope want to start reading the image data from the end of the file. Another option is to read the file in order and store the lines to bottom of the frame buffer first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are using a USB drive has nothing to do with what you want to do.

What matters is you seem to be using FatFS library to access the file system.

FatFS does not provide a standard C file API so there is no matching fseek() function to seek using the end of file as origin and then read the file position indicator with ftell() to find the size of the file.

Each file begins at offset 0 and ends at offset size-1.

If you want to seek to end, then there are two options.

If file is opened in read-only mode, you can try to seek to offset that is larger than the file.

Or, you can get the size of the file with f_size() and you know how long the file is and what is the last offset and where to f_seek() if you want to read a .BMP file one line at a time.

Of course you could just believe the .BMP header about file size to be correct as you need anyway multiple pieces of information such as how many lines there are in the file to read and what is the length of each line in bytes based on pixel data format.

Depending on what you want to do with the file, you could also just read the image data as it is in the file and write the data from end to beginning of your frame buffer.